# Range not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to Google App Script and I have a very basic question.

The following code gives me an error "Range not found". What I want to do is to fill an array with values (which are in the google sheet). Then I want to work with the values.

Function is linked to a button:

```
 function today(){

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 

  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B2");
  var values = range.getValues();

sheet.setActiveSelection(values[1, 1]);
```

Comment: The argument must be a range, you are giving a value in the setActiveSelection statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Adding Your Own Values

Here's how you can add your own values to a sheet.

```
function addMyValues(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];//this is a square matrix 
  sh.getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);//Creates a range with origin at row 1 column 1 and number of rows in values and number of columns in values
}
```

> When using setValues() it's always inportant to give it the correct range size or you will get errors.